# Stream output result text to speech

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, html

I need to live stream an output text to speech message Made by pressed button from a website. How can I achieve this? I tried Node.js to stream but I don't know how to stream after pressed button that generates the text to speech file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this solution that solves my problem... but return back an infinite loop after new mp3 is dynamically generated and played. how can I pause it while check for the new track and play new track dynamically built?

```
<audio id="audio" autoplay controls src="richiesta.php" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById('audio').addEventListener("ended",function() {
            this.src = "richiesta.php?nocache="+new Date().getTime();
            this.play();
    });

 </script>
```